# Almost sure convergence of positive random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I have a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space. The variables are known to be non-negative, i.e., $X_n \ge 0$ for all $n$. If we assume that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \: \mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0,$$

then, can we show that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \: X_n = 0$$

almost surely?

---

My tentative proof is as follows. The expected value of $X_n$ is

$$\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \int_{\Omega} X_n(\omega) \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega).$$

If we apply Fatou's Lemma we conclude that

$$\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} X_n(\omega) \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) = 0,$$

where the right-hand side is 0 by assumption. Since each $X_n \ge 0$, then $\liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) \ge 0$ for all $\omega$. Therefore, the left-hand side is also $\ge 0$ and, thus, it is $=0$. Therefore we can conclude that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n = 0$$

almost surely.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.